# Linear Regression with both variables centered on 0

Tags: regression, zero-inflation

Just a question to be sure, if my dependent variable and independant variable are centered on 0, how do I interpret correctly the linear regression ?

The intercept must be significant for the slope to have a real effect no?

[image]

Output example for one of the graph

```
                          Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                  19.41    1245.22   0.016    0.988    
Diff_Bedeckungsgrad_7Tage  4278.95     620.48   6.896 9.33e-12 ***
```

Comment: People are going to assume what you don't spell out, i.e. that centering is subtracting the mean.

Comment: I don't think so. If this was the case, the estimate should be zero

Comment: @niandra82 That is a good point except that I can't see that a line with intercept of 19.41 corresponds to **_any_** of the graphs. Hence I guess that the table refers to something else.

Comment: yes the scatter plot is inverted compared to the linear regression that is why, I will reedit

Answer (score 3):

A significant intercept means that It can be assumed different from zero. In your case, by construction, the intercept should be zero, i.e. p value greater than 0.05.

To be more precise, you should use a model with no intercept, because you don't have it